# Unable to load the packages (ex: googlesheets)

Tags: r

I just installed the `googlesheets` package and later i called the `library("googlesheets)`, but it could not executed and gave the error like :

```
library(googlesheets)
Error in library(googlesheets) : 
  there is no package called ‘googlesheets’.
```

Can any one help here

```
install.packages("googlesheets")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/eduru.suresh/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is
  later:
             binary source needs_compilation
googlesheets  0.2.2  0.3.0             FALSE

installing the source package ‘googlesheets’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/googlesheets_0.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2187937 bytes (2.1 MB)
downloaded 2.1 MB

* installing *source* package 'googlesheets' ...
** package 'googlesheets' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called 'pillar'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'googlesheets'
* removing 'C:/Users/eduru.suresh/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/googlesheets'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\eduru.suresh\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\EDURU~1.SUR\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEB1KKI/downloaded_packages/googlesheets_0.3.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘googlesheets’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\eduru.suresh\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEB1KKI\downloaded_packages’
> library(googlesheets)
Error in library(googlesheets) : 
  there is no package called ‘googlesheets’
```

Comment: "there is no package called 'pillar'" Did you try installing `pillar`? Or installing `googlesheets` from binary instead of source, i.e. choosing "no" at the prompt?

Comment: i installed pillar , for pillar also it is coming the same error

Comment: And did you try installing the binary instead of from source?

Comment: no and what is the binary here?

Comment: Look at my first comment and at the output you posted. You're prompted for whether you want to install `googlesheets` from source (answering "y") or from the binary (answering "n"). Based on the output you posted, you answered yes. Answering no would have it installed from the binary

Comment: yah i got it. Thank you